# Phonegap Build IOS13 - 13.2 keyboard Dictation / Speech to text no longer working

Tags: cordova, keyboard, phonegap, ios13, dictation

In my phonegap build app, I have found that after upgrading to ios version 13 - 13.2 the dictation (microphone / speech to text button) is no longer working properly.

to recreate:
--place cursor into a text field 
--press microphone button and start talking
--The microphone will only catch the first one to two seconds, then stop recording

It seems to be a problem with all of the 3rd party keyboard plugins.

Has anyone found a fix or a work around for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  The problem seems to be only present in UIWebView.  Once I transitioned my project to WKWebView, the problem went away.

Here are [instructions](https://medium.com/@palakash/transition-from-uiwebview-to-wkwebview-ios-e40e4b8ee9aa) on how to transition from UIWebView to WKWebView.

Answer (score 1):

We are also facing same issue in our application.

Is there any way to fix it using UIWebView?

We have an application developed based on UIWebView and changing it WKWebView would be riskier and require full testing cycle. We can take it parallel,  looking for a quick fix if any?

Thanks!

Manish Kumar

Comment: Hi @Manish Kumar, were you able to solve this problem somehow using UIWebView?